# Error: Expression does not produce a value

Tags: c#, vb.net

I tried to convert following C# code into VB.NET and got "Expression does not produce a value" error while compiling the code

C# Code

```
        return Fluently.Configure().Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<MyEntityMapping>())
            .Database(SQLiteConfiguration.Standard.InMemory().ShowSql())
            .ExposeConfiguration(x => new SchemaExport(x).Execute(false, true, false))
            .BuildSessionFactory();
```

VB.NET Code

```
    Return Fluently.Configure() _
        .Mappings(Function(m) m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf(Of SubscriptionMap)()) _
        .Database(SQLiteConfiguration.Standard.InMemory().ShowSql()) _
        .ExposeConfiguration(Function(x) New SchemaExport(x).Execute(False, True, False)) _
        .BuildSessionFactory()
```

The error happens on 2nd last line of VB.NET code, while C# code is compiled without problem.

What is wrong with the converting?

Thanks

---

Answer (score 5):

You need to create a `Sub(x)`, not a `Function(x)`.

Comment: If I change to `Sub(x) New SchemaExport(x).Execute(False, True, False)` now I got Syntax error on that New.

Comment: You need to upgrade to VB.Net 2010

Comment: I don't know  what the problem is; sorry.

Comment: I found solution by myself, check http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/54416394-9e04-4064-bb41-dc0ec76fb42b even I don't understand why.

Comment: @hardywang: Now I get it.  The problem is that VB.Net does not support statements of the form `New X().Y()`.  (unlike C#, which does)

Comment: But it probably does `(New X()).Y`

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes: No; it doesn't.

Comment: @SLaks: The following code compiles: `Dim xx = (New Queue()).Count`.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes: For that, you don't even need parentheses.  However, a _statement_ cannot start with `New`; the following statement does not compile: `(New StringWriter("")).WriteLine()`