# C# to VB.net conversion fix

Tags: c#, vb.net, automation, ui-automation

Hey all I have converted the following C# code:

```
if (Common.StartTask(() => Common.ClickButtonNtimes("SmallDecrement", "QuantityUpDown", 99))) return;
```

into VB.net:

```
If Common.StartTask(Function() Common.ClickButtonNtimes("SmallDecrement", "QuantityUpDown", 99)) Then
    Return
End If
```

However, I am getting an error on the line

```
Common.ClickButtonNtimes("SmallDecrement", "QuantityUpDown", 99))
```

of the VB code above:

> Expression does not produce a value.

The class in C# that is being called looks like this:

```
internal static void ClickButtonNtimes(string automationId, string windowId, int count)
{
        try
        {
            var condition = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, windowId);
            var button = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Subtree, condition);
            condition = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, automationId);
            button = button.FindFirst(TreeScope.Subtree, condition);
            InvokePattern clickButton = (InvokePattern)button.GetCurrentPattern(InvokePattern.Pattern);
            for (int i = 1; i < count; i++)
                clickButton.Invoke();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ERROR + automationId);
            Thread.Sleep(_timeout);
        }
    }
```

And also converting the above class into VB.net:

```
Friend Shared Sub ClickButtonNtimes(automationId As String, windowId As String, count As Integer)
        Try
            Dim condition = New PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, windowId)
            Dim button = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Subtree, condition)

            condition = New PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, automationId)
            button = button.FindFirst(TreeScope.Subtree, condition)

            Dim clickButton As InvokePattern = DirectCast(button.GetCurrentPattern(InvokePattern.Pattern), InvokePattern)

            For i As Integer = 1 To count - 1
                clickButton.Invoke()
            Next
        Catch generatedExceptionName As Exception
            MessageBox.Show([ERROR] & automationId)
            Thread.Sleep(_timeout)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All i needed to do was rename **function** to **sub**:

```
If Common.StartTask(Sub() Common.ClickButtonNtimes("SmallDecrement", "QuantityUpDown", 99)) Then
     Return
End If
```

As answered by @SLaks [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8617657/error-expression-does-not-produce-a-value)

And now it works just fine!